# How do I find the last descendent of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find last descendent div of the html below. 
I tried but it finds the first occurrence of the div.

How can I achieve this?

HTML:

```
<div class='greatparent'>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            find this div element
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.greatparent').find('div:last-child').html('you found me');
```

Comment: I don't think there's a selector for this, you'll need to write a recursive function to do it.

Comment: `:last-child` gets a DIV that's the last one among its siblings. All your DIVs are the only child of their parent, so the first div is also the last div.

Comment: oh really?? then I think the javascript guyz should bring a selector for this.

Comment: It doesn't seem like something that would be needed much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this using jQuery by finding the only `<div>` element that doesn't have a `<div>` child:

```
$(".greatparent").find("div:not(:has(div))")
```

Comment: Probably should be `$(".greatparent").find(yourselector)`

Comment: What if the div has, purposefully, a `span`, `<em>` or `<li>`? Can you add a test case, please?

Comment: Maybe should be `:not(:has(div))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery `:last` selector

```js
var last = $(".greatparent div:last");
console.log(last.children().length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class='greatparent'>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            find this div element
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```